# Erro Entity Framework mapeamento de classes a partir de banco existente

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Tenho um banco de dados SQL Server e mandei gerar as classes de mapeamento automaticamente a partir do database existente. Porém, quando executo a aplicação, dá o seguinte erro:

> (404,10) : error 3015: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 46, 404: Foreign key constraint 'PROCESSO_EMPRESA_ORDEM_SERVICO' from table ORDEM_SERVICO (COD_EMPRESA, COD_PROCESSO) to table PROCESSO_EMPRESA (COD_PROCESSO, COD_EMPRESA):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side.

As classes ORDEM_SERVICO e PROCESSO_EMPRESA abaixo:

```
public partial class ORDEM_SERVICO
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ORDEM_SERVICO()
    {
      FALTA_PECA = new HashSet<FALTA_PECA>();
      MENSAGEM = new HashSet<MENSAGEM>();
      ORDEM_SERVICO_ACESSOS = new HashSet<ORDEM_SERVICO_ACESSOS>();
      ORDEM_SERVICO_HISTORICO = new HashSet<ORDEM_SERVICO_HISTORICO>();
      ORDEM_SERVICO_HISTORICO_REPLANEJAMENTO = new HashSet<ORDEM_SERVICO_HISTORICO_REPLANEJAMENTO>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]    
    public int COD_EMPRESA { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime DAT_INCLUSAO { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int COD_USUARIO_CADASTRO { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string NUM_OS { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string DSC_NRO_DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE { get; set; }


    public int COD_PROCESSO { get; set; }

    public int? IND_SITUACAO { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string IND_TIPO_OS { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string IND_TIPO_SERVICO { get; set; }

    public int? COD_ETAPA_ATUAL { get; set; }

    public int? COD_ETAPA_ATUAL_SITUACAO { get; set; }

    public int? COD_IMPEDIMENTO_ATUAL { get; set; }

    public int? COD_SEGURADORA { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DAT_ENTRADA { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DATA_AUTORIZACAO { get; set; }

    public int? DIAS_PREVISAO_SAIDA { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DAT_PREVISAO_SAIDA { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DAT_SAIDA { get; set; }

    public int? COD_CONSULTOR { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string DSC_PENDENCIA_CADASTRO { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DAT_ALTERACAO { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string IND_ATIVO { get; set; }

    [StringLength(31)]
    public string COD_OS { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DAT_SINCRONISMO { get; set; }

    public int? COD_MOTIVO_ATRASO { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string IND_SITUACAO_ENTREGA { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string TIPO_SEGURADORA { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal? VALOR_FRANQUIA { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string NUM_SINISTRO { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string NOME_CORRETOR { get; set; }

    public virtual CLIENTE CLIENTE { get; set; }

    public virtual CONSULTOR CONSULTOR { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<FALTA_PECA> FALTA_PECA { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MENSAGEM> MENSAGEM { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ORDEM_SERVICO_ACESSOS> ORDEM_SERVICO_ACESSOS { get; set; }

    public virtual ORDEM_SERVICO_CRM_PERIODICIDADE_RETORNO_CLIENTE ORDEM_SERVICO_CRM_PERIODICIDADE_RETORNO_CLIENTE { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ORDEM_SERVICO_HISTORICO> ORDEM_SERVICO_HISTORICO { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ORDEM_SERVICO_HISTORICO_REPLANEJAMENTO> ORDEM_SERVICO_HISTORICO_REPLANEJAMENTO { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("COD_PROCESSO, COD_EMPRESA")]
    public virtual PROCESSO_EMPRESA PROCESSO_EMPRESA { get; set; }

    public virtual PROCESSO_ETAPA PROCESSO_ETAPA { get; set; }

    public virtual PROCESSO_ETAPA PROCESSO_ETAPA1 { get; set; }

    public virtual PROCESSO_IMPEDIMENTO PROCESSO_IMPEDIMENTO { get; set; }

    public virtual SEGURADORA SEGURADORA { get; set; }

    public virtual TIPO_SERVICO TIPO_SERVICO { get; set; }

    public virtual USUARIO USUARIO { get; set; }

    public virtual ORDEM_SERVICO_VEICULO ORDEM_SERVICO_VEICULO { get; set; }
}

public partial class PROCESSO_EMPRESA
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PROCESSO_EMPRESA()
    {
        ORDEM_SERVICO = new HashSet<ORDEM_SERVICO>();
        PAINEL_CONTROLE = new HashSet<PAINEL_CONTROLE>();
        PROCESSO_ETAPA_EMPRESA_SLA = new HashSet<PROCESSO_ETAPA_EMPRESA_SLA>();
        PROCESSO_IMPEDIMENTO_EMPRESA_SLA = new HashSet<PROCESSO_IMPEDIMENTO_EMPRESA_SLA>();
        PROCESSO_SITUACAO_DATA_OS_EMPRESA_SLA = new HashSet<PROCESSO_SITUACAO_DATA_OS_EMPRESA_SLA>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int COD_PROCESSO { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int COD_EMPRESA { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DAT_INCLUSAO { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DAT_ALTERACAO { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string IND_ATIVO { get; set; }

    public virtual EMPRESA EMPRESA { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ORDEM_SERVICO> ORDEM_SERVICO { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PAINEL_CONTROLE> PAINEL_CONTROLE { get; set; }

    public virtual PROCESSO PROCESSO { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PROCESSO_ETAPA_EMPRESA_SLA> PROCESSO_ETAPA_EMPRESA_SLA { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PROCESSO_IMPEDIMENTO_EMPRESA_SLA> PROCESSO_IMPEDIMENTO_EMPRESA_SLA { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PROCESSO_SITUACAO_DATA_OS_EMPRESA_SLA> PROCESSO_SITUACAO_DATA_OS_EMPRESA_SLA { get; set; }
}
```

Lembrando que o banco já existe e não posso modificá-lo.

Comment: Diego, no seu projeto foi database first certo? Se foi vai até o diagrama de gerado pelo entity clica com o botão direito e manda atualizar, pode ser isso!

Comment: Então, na verdade foi code first, ainda não sei como arrumar. Vou tentar criar de novo usando database first pra vê se dá certo.